# Multicolumn figure caption?

Tags: floats, rotating, columns

I have a landscape figure in a portrait article inserted as a `sidewaysfigure*` from package `rotating`.

Now, when I add (also landscape) caption to the figure, the lines become ca 25 cm long, which is impractical. So I think about typesetting the caption in 2 or 3 columns. How to do it?

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c@{}c}
        & \textbf{Palette} & \textbf{Stairs} & \textbf{Rubble} & \textbf{Rubble} & \textbf{Forest} & \textbf{Forest} \\
        % other large stuff
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{This long text needs to be multicolumn.}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

I tried using the `multicol` package and enclosing the caption in a `multicols` environment (and also putting the environment inside the caption). This correctly shrinks the text to one column, but `\columnbreak` commands do not work so I can't use the other two columns.

I tried putting two minipages inside the caption, but that's syntax error.

Comment: Which document class do you use? What are the dimensions of the textblock? Why are you using `sidewaysfigure` instead of `sidewaystable` if the important part of the environment is a `tabular` environment? What is the purpose of having an exceedlingly long caption that needs to be distributed across several columns -- why isn't that material placed inside the `sidewaysfigure` (or, perhaps better, `sidewaystable`) environment?

Comment: Simply - I don't know about `sidewaystable`. I'll try it. I use `article` document class. The figure content is generated in Matlab, so I don't consider it a good idea adding the caption there.

Comment: Wow, `sidewaystable` supports the columnbreaks, so I got what I wanted. Thanks! (you could convert your comment into an answer)

Comment: I've taken you up on your suggestion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given that a major part of the sideways-oriented environment is some tabular material, I would use a `sidewaystable` environment instead of a `sidewaysfigure` environment.
- I would keep the table's caption short and place any extra, explanatory material inside a `multicols` environment *inside* the `sidewaystable`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,multicol,lipsum,booktabs,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Palette} & \textbf{Stairs} & \textbf{Rubble} & 
\textbf{Rubble}  & \textbf{Forest} & \textbf{Forest} &
\textbf{Rubble}  & \textbf{Forest} & \textbf{Forest} \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\justifying % back to fully-justified text
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-2] % filler text
\end{multicols}
\caption{A short and snappy table caption}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```